# Automatically Concatenate Strings and Int C++

Tags: c++, c++11, concatenation

In Lua (apologise, I like working with it the best), the conversion between int and string is done automatically, so

```
"hi"..2
```

would result as

```
"hi2"
```

In C++ (cause I can't seem to get the default C++11 `stoi()` and `to_string()` methods to work) I defined these for myself:

```
int stoi(string str) {
  char* ptr;
  strtol(str.c_str(), &ptr, 10);
}

string to_string(int i) {
  char* buf;
  sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
  return buf;
}
```

which are basically how the default ones are defined anyways.

Then I did this:

```
string operator+ (string& stuff, int why) {
  stuff.append(to_string(why));
}
```

I tried it on the following code:

```
void print(string str) {
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main() {
  cout << stoi("1") + 2 << endl;
  print("die" + 1);
  return 0;
}
```

And it outputs

```
3
ie
```

Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
Here's what the code looks like now:

```
using namespace std;    

string to_string(int i) {
  char* buf;
  sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
  return buf;
}

string operator+ (string stuff, int why) {
  stuff.append(to_string(why));
  return stuff;
}

int main() {
  cout << string("die") + 2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And it just keeps giving me stackdumps.

Comment: What do you thinkg this `char* buf;  sprintf(buf, "%d", i);` does? `buf` just points anywhere, but certainly not to a valid region to write into.

Comment: erm, obvious question, what do you mean you can't get `std::to_string()` to work? this seems to work fine for me??

Comment: It tells me that `to_string()` has not been declared.

Comment: It's supposedly in C++11, and even though im using `-std=c++14` during compilation and `#include <string>` I still can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Replace `print("die" + 1);` with `cout << std::string("die") + 1;`

`print()` doesn't know what to do with strings. Use `std::cout`. "die" is a `char*`, `+1` will increment the pointer.

Comment: or `cout << "die" << 1;` :)

Comment: Good point  @fjardon. I missed that obvious answer. I tried to preserve the use of the  ̀+` operator.

Comment: I know you can do that, it's just that I was interested in seeing if I could implement some of the conveniences of Lua in C++

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string to_string(int i) {
  char buf[(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+2)/3+3];
  sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
  return buf;
}
```

You need to make an actual buffer to print to.  The math is a quick over-estimate of big the largest decimal `int` is in characters; 3 bits can fit in 1 decimal character, plus null, plus negation, plus rounding, plus 1 for good measure.  Hopefully I did not err: do some testing.

Also use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` while you are at it: buffer overflows are not to be toyed with.

The next problem is that `"hello"` is not a `std::string`,  It is a `char const[6]` -- an array of 6 `char`.  It can be converted tom`std::string`, but `+1` will instead convert it to a pointer to the first character, then `+1` it to the 2nd character.

Cast it to `std::string` before.

Finally, it is ambiguous in the standard (really) of pverloading an operator on `std::string + int` is legal.  It is definitely poor practice, as you cannot do it in `std` legally, and you should overload operators in the type's namespace (so ADL works): these two conflict.  On top of that, if `std` in the future adds such a `+` your code starts behaving strangely.  On top of that, operators are part of a class's interface, and modifying the interface of a class you do not 'own' is rude and a bad habit.

Write your own string class that owns a `std::string` rather.  Or a string view.

Finally, consider telling your compiler to use c++11, you probably just need to pass a flag to it like `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string s1("h1");
std::string s2("2");
s1 += s2;
```

If you are using C++11 compatible compiler you can convert int to string like this:

```
int i = 2;
std::string s = std::to_string(i);
```

If you are using Boost library:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int i = 2;
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
```

Please do not use raw char pointers in C++ for strings.

Answer (score 1):

overloading the operator+ on other than your own types it at best dangerous.

Just use `std::to_string` in conjunction with `operator+` or `+=`, e.g.

```
std::string x = "hi";
x += std::to_string(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++14 introduces a user-defined literal that takes a string literal (conversions are applied to make this a pointer) and returns a `std::string`. In C++11, you can just write your own (this is taken from libstdc++):

```
inline std::string
operator""_s(const char* str, size_t len)
{ 
  return std::string{str, len}; 
}
```

(Note: UDLs without a preceding underscore are reserved names)

And you can use it like this:

```
// Assumes operator+ is overloaded
print("die"_s + 1);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac27b1534bcff81e)

Comment: `__str` and `__len` is technically reserved too.

Answer (score -1):

`"die"` is not a `std::string`. It's a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Thus when you add 1 to the string literal, it decays to a `const char*` and the `+ 1` simply increments that pointer — to next char, `'i'`.

Then you call `print` with the incremented pointer, which causes a `std::string` to be constructed using that pointer. Since it pointed to the `'i'` character, to constructed string is initialized to `"ie"`.

You must first make a `std::string` out of your string literal to make it call your `operator+`:

```
std::cout << std::string("die") + 1;
```

And then make a few fixes to your `operator+`:

```
string operator+ (string stuff, int why) {
  return stuff.append(to_string(why));
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: `"die"` is not a `const char*`. It's an array of const char which decays to a pointer. The binary `+` operator doesn't increment anything either (that terminology implies one of the operands was modified). You also can't overload an operator that doesn't take at least one parameter of class type.

Comment: Yeah it throws me an error saying that it must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? You should tell what's wrong instead of just silently downvoting. Also you can simply not vote if you haven't got anything to say, doesn't hurt anybody.

Comment: Improvement suggestion: `template<class Rhs,class=typename enable_if<is_convertible<decltype(to_string(declval<Rhs>())), string>::value>::type> string operator+(string lhs, Rhs&&rhs){return lhs.append(to_string(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)));}` and now anything with a `std::string to_string` overload can be added.  (or write a separate trait for `can_to_string` and use it instead, or use tag dispatching, or etc)